# php preg_match_all for specific value

Tags: php, preg-match

I have a html content which has a URL fragment looks like following:

```
<a href="#/news/0294928/what-a-great-idea">
```

What I need to do is just to grab the number followed by #/news/

Any good idea? 
I tried following, but it gets only 4 results for me

```
preg_match_all('/<a href="#\/news\/(.+)\/?\"?>/i', $html_cont, $matches );
```

Please help me,
Thanks.

Comment: First you extract the href attribute using XPath, then you explode the result with `/` and you take the item number 2.

Comment: Grab using javascript's window.location.href and then split on the /.  From there it's the third item in the resulting array.

Comment: There are many other <a href="http:// ...> element. I just need href which starts with #/news

Comment: Do not parse HTML with regular expressions. Use [the proper tools](http://php.net/domdocument).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$string = '<a href="#/news/0294928/what-a-great-idea">';
preg_match_all("/#\/news\/(.*?)\//",$string, $m);
echo '<pre>'.print_r($m[1]).'</pre>';
```

so in $m[1] are all your numbers if thats what ure lookin for?

Comment: Oh. WHAT A GREAT !!!

Answer (score 0):

The detail of my comment:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHTML($yourHTML);

$xp = new DOMXPath($dom);
$hrefNodeList = $xp->query('//a/@href[starts-with(., "#/news/")]');

foreach ($hrefNodeList as $hrefNode) {
    echo explode('/', $hrefNode->nodeValue)[2] . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: any idea with preg_match_all() ?

Comment: @WilsonBreiner: a precise idea if you want to know, but I avoid shitty code.